# Angularjs-toaster always displays toast notification on top-right

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, toastr, ngtoast

I have this sample html file. Here I am using angular-toast notification. Issue I am facing here is toast messages always appear on the top-right position.

script.js file contains

```
    angular.module('main', ['ngAnimate', 'toaster']).controller('myController', function($scope,toaster, $window) {

        $scope.pop = function(){
            toaster.pop('success', "title", 'message');
        };

        $scope.clear = function(){
            toaster.clear();
        };
    });
```

Please find the plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/pzuW5OVkoxLF7zl0mGaC?p=preview

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your options you want: `position-class`, not `positionClass`.

Comment: Thanks alot..I took the reference of demo file of toaster and copied the same. Result it dint work..Thanks once again for saving my day :)

Answer (score 4):

I've added the below code for completeness:

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000, 'position-class': 'toast-bottom-left', 'close-button':true, 'animation-class': 'toast-bottom-left'}"></toaster-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify it to:

```
'position-class': 'toast-bottom-right','close-button':true
```